# Sublime Text 3 - key bindings for my macro don't work

Tags: binding, macros, key, sublimetext3

My macro code for Sublime Text 3 is:

```
[
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+l"], "command": "run_macro_file", "args": {"file": "C:/Users/mig2039/AppData/Roaming/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/LE CASE MDREC.sublime-macro"} }
```

]

The default key bindings work but this user-generated one won't work. I've tried a number of key bindings with no success.

The macro does work when I click through Tools > Macros > User > LE CASE MDREC.

Any help? Am new to Sublime.

Comment: have you tried changing the `file` argument value to `"res://Packages/User/LE CASE MDREC.sublime-macro"`?

Comment: IT WORKED - THANK YOU! How did that fix the problem? I hope to understand for next time.

Comment: In a nutshell Sublime doesn't accept absolute paths to things like Macros or snippets because they need to be a part of a package and packages are already in a location that it knows about. The `res://` tells Sublime that this is a package resource. This makes sure that these kinds of commands always work even if you're using the portable version of sublime, where the path might be different.